# How do I use custom stopwords and stemmer file in WEKA (Java)?

Tags: java, weka

So far I have:

```
NGramTokenizer tokenizer = new NGramTokenizer();
tokenizer.setNGramMinSize(2);
tokenizer.setNGramMaxSize(2); 
tokenizer.setDelimiters("[\\w+\\d+]");

StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
// customize filter here
Instances data = Filter.useFilter(input, filter);
```

The API has these two methods for StringToWordVector:

```
setStemmer(Stemmer value);
setStopwordsHandler(StopwordsHandler value);
```

I have a text file containing the stopwords and another class that stems words. How do I use a custom stemmer and stopwords filter? Note that the I'm taking phrases of size 2, so I can't preprocess and remove all stopwords beforehand.

**Update:** This worked for me (using Weka developer version 3.7.12)

To use a custom stopwords handler:

```
public class MyStopwordsHandler implements StopwordsHandler {

    private HashSet<String> myStopwords;

    public MyStopwordsHandler() {
        //Load in your own stopwords, etc.
    }

    //Must implement this method from the StopwordsHandler interface
    public Boolean isStopword(String word) {
        return myStopwords.contains(word); 
    }

}
```

To use a custom stemmer, create a class that implements the Stemmer interface and write the implementations for these methods:

```
public String stem(String word) { ... }
public String getRevision() { ... }
```

Then to use your custom stopwords handler and stemmer:

```
StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
filter.setStemmer(new MyStemmer());
filter.setStopwordsHandler(new MyStopwordsHandler());
```

**Note:** The answer below by Thusitha works for the stable 3.6 verion, and it is much simpler than the one described above. But I could not get it to work with the 3.7.12 version.

Comment: If by custom, you also want to use regular expressions as specification for stopwords, this might be of interest for you: http://www.giombetti.com/2016/03/06/using-a-regular-expression-to-specify-stop-words-in-weka-machine-learning-from-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest weka library you can use

```
StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
filter.setStopwords(new File("filename"));
```

I'm using following dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
   <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.12</version>
</dependency>
```

In the API docs
[API Doc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html)

> public void setStopwords(java.io.File value)
>       sets the file containing the stopwords, null or a directory unset the stopwords. If the file exists, it automatically turns on the flag
>   to use the stoplist.
>       Parameters:
>       value - the file containing the stopwords

Comment: Which version is that? I have the latest developer version.

Comment: Hmm... I'm using the latest stable version, 3.7.12

Comment: hm may be they have removed it in the new release. I get the dependency from maven central :( that was the latest there

Comment: I checked the API there it is listed. So it must be there

Comment: I discovered another way. That line throws an error for me and setStopwords() is not listed as one of the available methods.

Comment: you may be using dev, use stable instead of dev